# In RTL mode(Arabic), the position of UIBarButtonItem is not correct

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

I have implemented LTR and RTL mode(Arabic) in my ipad app.
But the frame of UIBarButtonItem is not correct in RTL mode.
In LTR mode, I can get the correct position using following code.

```
let senderView : UIView = senderButton.value(forKey: "view") as! UIView
let senderFrame = senderView.frame
```

In above code snippet, senderButton is the UIBarButtonItem.

I have attached screenshots.
In screenshots, If I use the above code to get the position of upload button(red outline), result is (0,0) in RTL mode
[image: UIBarButtonItems]

If you have any solutions, let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Does the button itself (not the red outline) appear in the expected location in RTL?

Comment: yes, I am going to display the popover below the upload button. so I need to get the frame of upload button to set source view of popover. it works well in LTR mode but not worked in RTL mode. I have set the leftBarButtonItems and rightBarButtonItems in navigation bar.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qmo69cmvsrnvgf/Screen%20Shot%202017-12-18%20at%209.37.33%20PM.png?dl=0